# Resize SVG included from external file

Tags: html, css, svg

I just discovered the possibility to include svg from an external sprite and use them in the HTML through the `<use>` tag. This method gives me two benefits:

1. Define all the icons in one SVG file and use each of them on demand
2. I can manipulate directly the SVG icon, in particular with `fill` property

That saied, I'm now facing the problem of scaling the SVG. I read a couple of tutorials but I can't actually still set the SVG icon dimensions I want.
If it was a normal image I would have written a rule like:

```
.icon {
    width: 2em;
    height: auto;
}
```

I understood that with SVG this doesn't work since it's not an image.

- I tried to set the `viewBox` property but nothing actually happened.
- I tried to wrap the svg inside a `div` and set properties to it but nothing happened for the same reason as above, I guess.

***So, how can I resize my SVG icon?***

---

This is the future icons' collector file with just one icon at the moment `sprite.svg`

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<defs>
    <path id="right-arrow-1" class="icon-1" d="m40.4,121.3c-0.8,0.8-1.8,1.2-2.9,1.2s-2.1-0.4-2.9-1.2c-1.6-1.6-1.6-4.2 0-5.8l51-51-51-51c-1.6-1.6-1.6-4.2 0-5.8 1.6-1.6 4.2-1.6 5.8,0l53.9,53.9c1.6,1.6 1.6,4.2 0,5.8l-53.9,53.9z"/>
</defs>
```

And this is the HTML page:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="icon-wrap">
        <svg class="icon-x">
            <use href="/storage/icons/sprite.svg#right-arrow-1"></use>
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here I create a snippet with those three attempts with the svg directly in HTML (it doesn't matter if it comes from external file or not)

```css
.icon-2 {
  width: 5em;
  height:auto
  
}

.wrap {
  width: 5em;
  height:auto;
}

.icon-3 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


/* NOT important rules, just to let it more enjoyable */
.icon {
  fill: pink;
  -webkit-transition: fill linear 0.25s;
    -moz-transition: fill linear 0.25s;
    -ms-transition: fill linear 0.25s;
    -o-transition: fill linear 0.25s;
    transition: fill linear 0.25s;
}

.icon:hover {
  fill: red;
  -webkit-transition: fill linear 0.25s;
    -moz-transition: fill linear 0.25s;
    -ms-transition: fill linear 0.25s;
    -o-transition: fill linear 0.25s;
    transition: fill linear 0.25s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <svg class="icon icon-1">
            <path id="right-arrow-1" class="icon-x" d="m40.4,121.3c-0.8,0.8-1.8,1.2-2.9,1.2s-2.1-0.4-2.9-1.2c-1.6-1.6-1.6-4.2 0-5.8l51-51-51-51c-1.6-1.6-1.6-4.2 0-5.8 1.6-1.6 4.2-1.6 5.8,0l53.9,53.9c1.6,1.6 1.6,4.2 0,5.8l-53.9,53.9z"/>
    </svg>
    <br>
    
    <svg class="icon icon-2">
        <path id="right-arrow-1" class="icon-x" d="m40.4,121.3c-0.8,0.8-1.8,1.2-2.9,1.2s-2.1-0.4-2.9-1.2c-1.6-1.6-1.6-4.2 0-5.8l51-51-51-51c-1.6-1.6-1.6-4.2 0-5.8 1.6-1.6 4.2-1.6 5.8,0l53.9,53.9c1.6,1.6 1.6,4.2 0,5.8l-53.9,53.9z"/>
    </svg>
    <br>
    
    <div class="wrap">
        <svg class="icon icon-3">
          <path id="right-arrow-1" class="icon-x" d="m40.4,121.3c-0.8,0.8-1.8,1.2-2.9,1.2s-2.1-0.4-2.9-1.2c-1.6-1.6-1.6-4.2 0-5.8l51-51-51-51c-1.6-1.6-1.6-4.2 0-5.8 1.6-1.6 4.2-1.6 5.8,0l53.9,53.9c1.6,1.6 1.6,4.2 0,5.8l-53.9,53.9z"/>
    </svg>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to control the size of your svg with CSS you should use the viewBox attribute, which "allows you to specify that a given set of graphics stretch to fit a particular container element". 
You can find more details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox):

Example from your code:

```
<style>
  .icon-2 {height: auto; width: 15em;} /*change this and see results */ 
</style>

<svg class="icon icon-2" viewBox="0 0 150 150">
<path id="right-arrow-1" class="icon-x" d="m40.4,121.3c-0.8,0.8-1.8,1.2-2.9,1.2s-2.1-0.4-2.9-1.2c-1.6-1.6-1.6-4.2 0-5.8l51-51-51-51c-1.6-1.6-1.6-4.2 0-5.8 1.6-1.6 4.2-1.6 5.8,0l53.9,53.9c1.6,1.6 1.6,4.2 0,5.8l-53.9,53.9z"/>
</svg>
```

You could change the size with CSS.
Hope it helps!

Comment: You mean like `.icon-2 { width: 2em; font-size: 6px; }` ?

Comment: Please use comments for clarifying questions.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan - thanks! change it from comment to solution - i hope.

Comment: @A.Meshu do you know why we need to specify `viewBox` in `svg` tag in HTML file even if it is specified in external `symbol` tag?

Comment: @max https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53621262/why-do-i-need-to-specify-viewbox-property-when-im-referencing-svg-from-another