# Why do I need to specify viewBox property when I'm referencing SVG from another file which have viewBox specified?

Tags: html, svg

In my external file called `icons.svg` I have:

```
<symbol viewBox="0 0 1117.48 823.88" id="a_day_at_the_park" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<!-- ... -->
```

In my HTML:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 1117.48 823.88">
  <use xlink:href="icons.svg#a_day_at_the_park"></use>
</svg>

<svg>
  <use xlink:href="icons.svg#a_day_at_the_park"></use>
</svg>
```

The first one works good (with viewBox) - exactly like inline SVG.

What is the reason to specify `viewBox` in external file when it doesn't work when using it with `use`?

I would like to have the same result when I'm using `use` without having to specify `viewBox`. I have several icons which have different `viewBox` but it seems it's not possible and I always have to copy that to my HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `viewBox` tells the browser how the content of the SVG is to be positioned and scaled.  You need to have it on any SVG if you want it to be responsive, or if the content inside the SVG is drawn at a different scale from the final size it will be rendered at.

For example, if your SVG is always going to be 24x24, and your content (that includes symbols) is within that 24x24 box, you don't need any viewBoxes.

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
  <symbol id="icon">
     <rect width="24" height="24" fill="orange"/>
     <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10" fill="red"/>
   </symbol>
 </svg>
  
 <svg width="24" height="24">
   <use href="#icon"/>
 </svg>
```

But if they are not designed to be scale 1:1, then the rendered SVG, will always need a `viewBox`.  However the symbol doesn't necessarily have to have one.

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
  <symbol id="icon">
     <rect width="100" height="100" fill="orange"/>
     <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="red"/>
   </symbol>
 </svg>
  
 <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
   <use href="#icon"/>
 </svg>
```

Comment: Thanks, so I can remove `viewBox` property from symbols to reduce file size and use it only on my HTML `svg`?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to.